# Rails select_tag onchange action WITHOUT Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

In my index action of the hours controller I want to be able to switch between the diplayed hours.
I am using a calendar_for table and inside the calendar I display the tracked times (hours) of the different user of my rails app.
As I am using a quite complex calendar structure with some calculation inside, I don't know how to extract it to a partial, so I want the onchange event, which fires in the select_tag, to reload the index action with a different parameter.

I tried

```
<% form_for :hours, :url => { :action => "index" } do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.find(:all), :id, :name),
  { :onchange => "this.form.submit();"} %>
<% end %>
```

but this brings me to the new / form view (like i want to add a new record)? also the url just shows `/hours`

Any help would be appreciated....

I basically want that after changing the select menu the url looks like `/hours?user_id=<id from select_tag>`

thanks

Comment: Once you submit a form in anyway, form elements hash should be submitted to your controller. Your existing code seems fine. All you need to do, I think, is in your controller, access the user_id with params[:user_id] and process it and redirect to any page you want. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand why do you need a form? The simplest way from my opinion is update your `application.js` file with something like this (assuming you use jquery):

```
$("#selector_id").change ( function () {
  window.location.replace('/hours?'+this.id);
});
```

Though probably there is some pretty rails helper for that.

Comment: cool! thanks... that solved my problem nice and unobstrusivly. I had to change it to window.location.replace('/hours?user_id='+$(this).val()); though...